# Angular image not served properly from nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, angular, frontend

I want to serve a image from my nodejs backend and show it in frontend, my backend running at 8081 port and frontend at 8080. I can see images in http://localhost:8081/image.JPG but in frontend I am getting 404 as it is looking for http://localhost:8081/image.JPG.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
global.__basedir = __dirname;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources/static/assets/uploads/'));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
 
const db = require('./app/config/db.config');

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}));
  
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
db.sequelize.sync({force: false}).then(() => {
  console.log('Drop and Resync with { force: false }');
}); 

require('./app/routers/upload.router.js')(app);
 
// Create a Server
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
 
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
 
  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
 
})
```

i can see image when i query in browser as it is looking for 8081 port

[image: back]

frontend looking for port 8080 so getting below error--

[image: front]

someone please suggest me a solution. I am not getting any clue. Thank you.

Comment: You simply have to use the full path like this `htttp://example.com/image.jpg` instead of just `/image.jpg`. If both hostname and port are not the same it's like it's different server.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that you can take is to use proxy config provided by Angular like below:

```
{
  "/api/assets": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8081",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Now, from the frontend when you hit this URL: `http://localhost:8080/api/assets/image.JPG` it will proxy to `http://localhost:8081/api/assets/image.JPG`

your image tag will look like `<img src="/api/assets/image.JPG">`

More on Proxy config & how to configure: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: but img src are coming from backend,<div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let imagefile of imageFiles">
      <div
        class="card"
        style="width: 25rem;">
        <img src={{imagefile.photo}} >